# Recommendations about making a modular design

Tags: python

I want future adding on to be super easy for my current project and I'm trying to have it so I can just add a module to a package and have it imported and implemented easily.

Right now, I have the following code. Is there a better way to handle what I want accomplished? I also have a question about pkgutil.walk_packages. It returns modules that are not in the "selected" package (parent.package.path). Any tips on how to fix that?

```
import pkgutil
import importlib

sub_modules = []
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages('parent.package.path'):
    if 'parent.package.path.' not in str(modname):
        continue
    sub_modules.append(str(modname))

for m in sub_modules:
    i = importlib.import_module(m)
    i.handle_command()
```

My goal is to add things to parent.package.path and have them activated by running the handle_command() method in each module.

Comment: This belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: What you are doing is actually part of designing modular code.  If you have 15 classes that all take the same input on the `handle_command` method, you are implementing an interface in which to code to.  Take a look at [SOLID principles](http://www.slideshare.net/DrTrucho/python-solid) as well.  This question is probably best for a site like reddit.com/r/learnpython or, like Akshat Mahajan said, on CodeReview.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan This question is misleadingly titled. "How to fix that?" makes this question [off-topic for Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Comment: @DuckPuncher I will take a look at that, thank you.

I realize what I'm doing is it being modular but is this the best way to handle it?

Comment: @Brandon, Honestly, it depends on what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to design code where you can drop in replacements then this is probably your best bet. For example, if you accept payments on a website, you could have different classes for each payment providers API. As long as they all have a `makePayment` method, you could drop any of those payment classes into a function/method that makes payments in order to utilize the different services. In python, I usually inherit from a parent class and override the interface method. This way you can do additional checks on class name.

Comment: @Brandon, the idea is to make your code expandable while closing the code for modifications.  Using this methodology does exactly this. You have code you can add functionality to without changing the underlying code.

Comment: @DuckPuncher Thanks. I'll see about using a parent class and going from there